# In python, why does the line after await sentence not be executed?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a piece of code to download data from commoncrawl using asynio. However, I found that my program only output "rest" in my console. It didn't print "in" or output to my cosole. (see my function download_url()). The whole process is displayed below. I just don't know why "print('in')" sentence didn't get executed and the program just exits normally.

```py
async def download_url(few_urls, tmp_folder, id, process_id):
    html_contents = []
    url = few_urls[0]
    leng, offset, website_url = url[0], url[1], url[2]
    start = int(offset)
    end = int(offset)+int(leng)-1
    header = {'Range': f'bytes={start}-{end}'}
    print(header)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('rest')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        async with session.get(website_url, headers=header) as response:
            print('in')
            output = await response.text()
            output = output.decode()
            print(output)
    return 

async def download_urls(urls, tmp_folder, process_id):
    url_blocks = []
    block_num = 10
    start = 0
    while start+block_num <= len(urls):
        url_blocks.append(urls[start:start+block_num])
        start += block_num
    if start < len(urls): url_blocks.append(urls[start:])

    tasks = []
    for i, url_block in enumerate(url_blocks):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(download_url(url_block, tmp_folder, i, process_id)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main(urls, tmp_folder, process_id):
    print(f'in main {process_id}')
    asyncio.run(download_urls(urls, tmp_folder, process_id))
```

I expect some people familiar to python asyncio to answer my question. Thanks! By the way, the python version is 3.8.

Comment: Can't reproduce. When calling with e.g. `main([(2000, 0, "https://cnn.com")], None, 1)` it prints "in" and raises an exception because `output` is already a `str` and therefore calling `output.decode()` is an error. Removing this line prints the expected HTML.